# Textarea width issue in firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a text area in a fixed width box. I'm struggling with browser compatibility. When I fix the width in chrome & IE, Firefox do not show proper spacing on right. Reducing cols fix issue on Firefox but on IE/Chrome, it show more space towards right.

I need textarea to be placed exactly in center in all browsers. Is it possible?

Demo code is given on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9GFpA/) as well as below:

**HTML**

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='box-title'>
        Title
    </div>
    <div class='box-cont'>
        This is the contents of content area.
        No limit for these contents.
        Width will be fixed but height may be infinite long
        depending on the contents
        <textarea rows='3' cols='35'></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
    width:312px;
    border:1px #666 solid;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
.box-title{
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border:1px #F66 solid;
    border-bottom:0;
    background-color:#FAA;
    padding:2px 5px;
    margin:0;
}
.box-cont{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    border:1px #F66 solid;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:2px 5px;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: It looks perfectly fine here (@ FF 15.0.1)

Comment: @c_kick Well I'm also using Firefox 15.0.1, IE9, Chrome 21 on Windows 7 for comparisons. For me, its perfectly centred in Chrome and IE but in firefox, it is crossing expected right border by around 2-3 pixels. I also tested on different machine but the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hi now give to **css** in your `textarea` as like this

```
.box-cont textarea{
width:100%;
    height:40px;
    resize:none;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9GFpA/1/)***

Comment: But, why? Why should he do this? What did you change and how does it function?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks i thing textarea some defult with every  in browser so that i define this width to according to parent .........

Comment: Thanks. Yes above styles fixed the issue.